# Optimizing this Validate method

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Is there any better and optimized way to write this code?

```
    public int ValidateEntries()
    {
        if (this.CompanyName.Length < 6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Company name must be of at least six characters.", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return 1;
        }

        if (DateTime.Parse(this.FYStarting) > DateTime.Parse(this.FYEnding))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid financial year period.", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;  //Default error code: 0 : No Error, 1 : Error
    }
```

I want to introduce **try..catch** block just in case any error fires. But it's going to create an overhead. I also want to get rid of these **if** s.

Thirdly, which is more optimized: **Convert.ToDateTime** or **DateTime.parse**?

Comment: Optimized for what?  Also you probably should not be interacting with the user in a validation method.

Comment: @recursive: Compiler optimizations for speed. I didn't understand the second part of your reply.

Comment: Using integer return values here is highly unidiomatic. You should either use exceptions or a `bool` return value.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks for the tip. Unidiomatic?

Comment: Are you kidding? What part of these few lines need optimization? It looks like you might need faster users to click through your messageboxes.

Comment: @RPK: As in "not the normal way of doing things in C#".

Comment: @GregS: No I am serious. It is just a sample code. There are many IF blocks inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declarative validation is an optimum way, Use the appropriate Validation framework that works for you (Like what you can find in [Entlib](http://entlib.codeplex.com/))

You must get rid off current solution and handle cross cutting concerns in a cleaner, easier and consistent way.

Answer (score 2):

Better approach is to divide data classes and UI. Using special interfaces, like [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) and validation patterns would help you to support your code in future.

Answer (score 2):

`try`...`catch` is relatively cheap. It only becomes expensive if an exception is thrown.

But I don't like the way you mix GUI and logic. I'd rather pass in an error list(in the simplest case a `List<string>` but can be more complex) and add errors to in in each validation clause. In the end you can check if any errors occurred with `errorlist.Count` and show the messages.

If your int will always only represent two values it would be better off as bool.

Simplified example:

```
public class ErrorList:List<string>
{
    public bool HasErrors{get{return Count>0;}}
}

public void ValidateEntries(ErrorList errors)
{
    if (this.CompanyName.Length < 6)
        errors.Add("Company name must be of at least six characters.");

    if (DateTime.Parse(this.FYStarting) > DateTime.Parse(this.FYEnding))
       Errors.Add("Invalid financial year period."
}

public void CallingFunction()
{
    var errors=new ErrorList();
    ValidateEntries();
    if(erros.HasErrors)
    {
        ShowMessage(string.Join("\r\n",errors));
        return;
    }
    DoStuff();
}
```

Depending on your architecture you can also create some helper functions or use a more declarative design. But it's hard to give more concrete tips without knowing your program better. For example in my code the validation doesn't even know what a `Form` is and operates on a `ViewModel` or even more low level structures.

And for example ASP.net MVC has it's built in mechanisms for dealing with validation and error-lists. So check what your framework offers.

Comment: The above code is in a different class, but true it is not a professional way. You mean I should add error codes in a List and in the end refer to the List whether it is empty or not?

Comment: Outside the validation method, you should deal with the list.  The way you have it now, the user must click "Ok" for every error.  They will be annoyed if there are more than 1.

Comment: Yes it's just simplified code. In practice you might want to write the error into a label next to the input field. This would also require extending the error-list to take fieldname-errormessage pairs. Or one could concat the messages with a linebreak inbetween and display it as one messagebox.